# API url from Curl

Tags: api, url, curl

I'm currently trying to use an api. I basically know how to do it, except that their documentation is not very well provided. They provide an example of a request with curl, which, when I enter it in my terminal, works, but I can't get the request via the url.
So my question is : is it possible, with a curl request, to get the generated url ?

[image: my code]

so i did that...
the result.json files only contain : "{"error":"invalid fields"}\n"

[image: got it !]

OKAY ! thanks i got it !

Comment: I mean, if I had the generated url, I could make my own...

Comment: Please provide a link to the api and possibly the curl command. Is it possible you used the wrong protocol? Also curl doesn't generate a url, did you mean the body?

Comment: You need to show the cURL command. You can replace the domain with example.com and redact API keys etc. if you don't want to show the actual data.

Comment: That's a POST request, so the URL stays the same. The data is passed in body, not in the URL.

Comment: Okay, i guess i get it.. so whats wrong with my code now ? what do i have to change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an array. Php will automatically convert this to a query string, your api expects a json string. Change `curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postRequest)` to `curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postRequest))`. You are also not setting headers, which might confuse the api.